# How can i use django groups for specific model?

Tags: django

does any body can help me to use Django groups for a specific model ?

for example for blog app,in Entry model, can i add a field like this to have groups like sport,news and etc ?

```
group = models.ForeignKey(groups,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
(something like this)
```

Comment: What should such group do?

Comment: to organize entries .

Comment: for example if i have a news model , how can i categorize entries in different categories like sport,financial and etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confusing Django User Groups with the groups you are looking for. You might want to create a new model called Category

```
class Category(models.Model):
    shortName = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    # Add other fields
```

Then update the Entry model with a foreign key to Category

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```